# Solve $z(1-q^2)=2(px+qy)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

My progress:

From auxiliary equation we can get that $ p=aq $

Substituting p in the equation we get $q=-\frac {ax+y}{z} \pm \sqrt{(\frac{ax+y}{z})^2 +1} $

using $dz=Pdx+qdy$

$zdz=-(ax+y)+\sqrt{(ax+y)^2+z^2} d(ax+y)$

I don't know how to progress from here or if the process is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partial solution seems correct, except for a typo in the last equation, which should be
$$
z\,dz=\left[-(ax+y)\pm\sqrt{(ax+y)^2+z^2}\right]d(ax+y). \tag{1}
$$
To proceed from there, let's rewrite $(1)$ as
$$
z\frac{dz}{d\xi}=-\xi\pm\sqrt{\xi^2+z^2}, \tag{2}
$$
where $\xi:=ax+y$. Adding $\xi$ to both sides of $(2)$, we obtain
$$
\xi+z\frac{dz}{d\xi}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{d\xi}(\xi^2+z^2)=\pm\sqrt{\xi^2+z^2}. \tag{3} 
$$
Defining $u:=\xi^2+z^2$, we may rewrite $(3)$ as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{du}{d\xi}=\pm\sqrt{u}, \tag{4}
$$
the solution of which is $u=(\xi+C)^2$. Replacing $u$ and $\xi$ with their definitions, and solving for $z$, we finally obtain
$$
z=\pm\sqrt{C^2+2C(ax+y)}. \tag{5}
$$